# Laravel audit log for model events using generic way

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel 5.2`.

I want to create audit log entries for each and every `model` in my project. Whenever any `model` gets `created, updated or deleted`; the audit log for that record should be logged along with old and new values.

For example if I update user's first name from `John` to `George`, the audit table entry should be logged something like `First name updated from John to George`.

I know I can fire created, updated and deleted events and using individual listners I can log this. But I want to create it more generic way.

I don't want to define `boot` method with `created`, `updated` and `deleted` `events` in each and every `model` as I have more than 75 `models` existing in my project. I don't like duplication of that method in each and every model. I want to make it more `generic` way, like use something like `trait`, using that in `model` should automatically identify which `event` is fired.

Again, the `listener` will also listen the event but not for any specific model but `generic`. I don't want any tight coupling. It should decide which model is updated and make entry of log according to that.

Can any one guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked out the [VentureCraft/revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) package?

Comment: @patricus it does not support Laravel 5.2. Please see Packgist link: https://packagist.org/packages/venturecraft/revisionable , also I am not able to execute the migration command given in the documentation for installation.

Comment: Where you want to save this log entry I mean to say in file or in database. As you have given example for user there will be two entries one with John and other with George this entries will be in file?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that it didn't support 5.2. I don't know if there is any reason it wouldn't other than the composer file needing to be updated. As far as the migration, their documentation just needs to be updated. Instead of the command given in the docs, you need to use `php artisan migrate --path=vendor/venturecraft/revisionable/src/migrations`. The `--package` option they use in the docs was removed in Laravel 5.